# How to return output of shell script into Jenkinsfile

Tags: bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkinsfile that calls a shell script:

```
        stage('Terraform Plan') {
            steps {
                    sh 'chmod +x ./jenkins_plan.sh'
                    sh 'bash jenkins_plan.sh'
            }
        }
```

The shell script (jenkins_plan.sh) has the following commands in it:

```
        cd "$dir"
        terraform init
        terraform validate 
        terraform plan -lock=false -input=false -out tfplan
        terraform show -no-color tfplan > tfplan.txt
```

I would like to send the output (tfplan.txt) from the shell script to the Jenkinsfile so I can do something similar to:

```
        stage('Terraform Plan') {
            steps {
                    sh 'chmod +x ./jenkins_plan.sh'
                    sh 'bash jenkins_plan.sh'
               script{
                    env.PLAN_OUTPUT = readFile('tfplan.txt')
                }
            }
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your TF CLI commands and JP code are both completely fine. Could you please elaborate on what the delta is between current and expected behavior?

Comment: I don't want to output everything using 'returnStdout', I would just like to get tfplan.txt and its contents from the shell script to the jenkinsfile. Currently with the way my code is setup, the tfplan.txt just returns null.

Comment: The `chmod +x jenkins_plan.sh` is superfluous if you always run the script with `bash jenkins_plan.sh`

Comment: A much better fix is to take out the hard-coded redirection within the script and then just capture its output.